# 3D plot matlab with 3 equally sized vectors

Tags: matlab, 3d

I have three vectors, X, Y, and Z. All of equal length (20000,1). I want to plot all three in a 3d plot. I have tried using `surf` and `plot3` but to no avail as they require Z to be of size (20000,20000). Can anybody help?
TIA

```
X = DAT(3,:);

Y = DAT(4,:);

Z = DAT(11,:);

[x,y] = meshgrid(X,Y);

surf(x,y,Z);
```

Comment: When you say you want to plot all three in a 3D plot, do you mean you want a single point in your plot for each [x, y, z]? If so, you can just use `plot3(X, Y, Z)`.

Comment: That does work but ideally I would like to get surf working as it is easier on the eye.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `griddata` or `TriScatteredInterp` to create an interpolated surface?

Answer (score 1):

NO! `plot3` does NOT require that of Z. If all you wish is to plot a point set, then `plot3` does EXACTLY what you want.

`plot3(X,Y,Z,'.')`

The point is, there is NO need to use `meshgrid` for `plot3`. In fact, there is no need to use `meshgrid` as you have tried in order to use `surf`. (If you will be calling `griddata`, then `meshgrid` would be necessary, but for a SMALLER mesh.)

IF you need a surface plot, then you need to create a surface. If the points are scattered, then your basic options are tools like `triscatteredinter`, `griddata`, or [`gridfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit), the last from the file exchange.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/311767 gives the code snippet may help you.

```
X=rand(1,30);
Y=rand(1,30);
Z=rand(1,30);

[XI YI ZI] = griddata(X,Y,Z,linspace(0,1),linspace(0,1)');

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
trisurf(delaunay(X,Y),X,Y,Z)
subplot(1,2,2);
surf(XI,YI,ZI)
```